# Scheduled sync adapter runs every 30 seconds

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

I use sync adapters in my application to sync changes from server periodically. No matter what value i put in the pollFrequency the sync runs every 30 seconds.

I checked on forum and tried the changes suggested in the replies and I pass 'false' as syncToNetwork parameter when I raise notifyChange on ContentResolver.

On going through the training again in detail, I stumbled upon this difference.

On Google developer site -> training section [Sync adapters training](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html) 
I see the addPeriodicSync -> pollFrequency parameter is passed in milliseconds

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
...
// Constants
// Content provider authority
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.datasync.provider";

// Account
public static final String ACCOUNT = "default_account";

// Sync interval constants
public static final long MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000L;
public static final long SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60L;
public static final long SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES = 60L;

//This is the line I'm referring to
public static final long SYNC_INTERVAL = SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES * 
                                         SECONDS_PER_MINUTE *
                                         MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;

// Global variables
// A content resolver for accessing the provider
ContentResolver mResolver;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    // Get the content resolver for your app
    mResolver = getContentResolver();
    /*
     * Turn on periodic syncing
     */
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(
            ACCOUNT,
            AUTHORITY,
            null,
            SYNC_INTERVAL);
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

On API reference [API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#addPeriodicSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20long%29) the pollFrequency is mentioned to be in seconds. What is the expected unit pollFrequency, milliseconds or seconds?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You should add
        **ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true);** to your code. Without this the setSyncAutomatically will be ignored.

Read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#setMasterSyncAutomatically(boolean))).

Answer (score 1):

Your `SYNC_INTERVAL` should be in seconds, not in milliseconds.

#### The addPeriodicSync() documentation says:

> pollFrequency how frequently the sync should be performed, in seconds.